# Why do I get random text appended to my STOMP protocol messages?

Tags: php, json, message-queue, hornetq, stomp

I'm having an issue where I'm able to write many json encoded arrays to HornetQ without any problem, but when I try to read the frames back, every n'th message has random text appended to it (usually MESSAGE or RECEIPT).

Example:

I send the following to HornetQ:

```
{"data":9933753,"more_data":"Some Text"}
```

and I get back the following when I read the frame body:

```
{"data":9933753,"more_data":"Some Text"}  

MESSAGE subscription:subscription/jms.queue.testing.qa.myqueue message-id:1310 
destination:jms.queue.testing.qa.myqueue expires:0 redelivered:false priority:4 timestamp:1382637077839
```

I read the STOMP protocol definition and I still don't get how I can get back just the json string that I sent without the extra text seeing as the MESSAGE is in the body itself (making it impossible to decode it back without doing hacky string manipulations).

I have the following setup:
HornetQ (latest)
PHP 5.4
STOMP library: http://stomp.fusesource.org/documentation/php/book.html

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: What version? There was a bug fix at some point as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug probably. there was a fix around that at some point as I remember. If you are still seeing it with the latest version you have to provide a testcase to the developers and we would gladly fix it. I'm speaking here as one of the developers.

But first check if you are on the latest version. (2.3.0+ or 2.4.0 beta), or any latest EAP version.

Comment: Thanks for the update. We ended up switching to a different queueing system since this is for a new project so I don't know if this would have fixed the problem, but I do believe we were using a new version.